# What else could we do, instead of solving the congruences?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, congruences, p-adic-number-theory

I want to find the p-adic expansion of $\frac{1}{p}$ and $\frac{1}{p^r}$ in the field $\mathbb{Q}_p$.

So, do I have to solve the congruences $px \equiv 1 \pmod {p^n}, p^r x \equiv 1 \pmod { p^n }, \forall n \in \mathbb{N} $, respectively?

But.. these congruences do not have solutions, right?

What else could we do, in order to find the p-adic expansion of $\frac{1}{p}$ and $\frac{1}{p^r}$ in $\mathbb{Q}_p$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, $\frac{1}{p^n}$ is its own $p$-adic expansion in $\mathbb{Q}_p$.

The congruence $px\equiv 1\mod p^n$ is equivalent to solving $$px-p^ny=1$$ for $x,y\in\mathbb{Z}$. This is impossible because it would imply that $p\mid 1$.

The $p$-adic expansion of a number $n$ looks like a Laurent series in $p$ with coefficients in $\mathbb{Z}/(p\mathbb{Z})$. So we have $$\frac{1}{p}=1\cdot p^{-1}+0+0\cdot p+0\cdot p^2+\ldots$$

Another way of seeing it is that every non-zero element of $\mathbb{Q}_p$ can be represented uniquely as $p^{n}z$ where $n\in\mathbb{Z}$ and $z\in(\mathbb{Z}_p)^{\times}$. The unit $z$ can be expanded as a $p$-adic integer series and then shifted $n$ units to the right or left by $p^{n}$.

### Proof:

First, I prove that it is possible to represent elements of $\mathbb{Q}_p$ in the form mentioned above. Let $0\neq q\in\mathbb{Q}_p$. Now define $z:=q\cdot\vert q\vert_p$. Calculating the norm of $z$ shows that it is a unit in $\mathbb{Z}_p$: $$\vert z\vert_p=\left\vert q\vert q\vert_p\right\vert_p=\left\vert qp^{-\nu_p(q)}\right\vert_p=\vert q\vert_p\cdot \left\vert p^{-\nu_p(q)}\right\vert_p=p^{-\nu_p(q)}\cdot p^{\nu_p(q)}=1.$$ This gives $q=\vert q\vert_p^{-1}z$. Where $\vert\cdot\vert_p$ is the [$p$-adic norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-adic_order#p-adic_Norm) and $\nu_p(\cdot)$ is the [$p$-adic valuation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-adic_order#Definition_and_Properties).

Second, I prove that there is only one such way to represent a given $p$-adic number. Let $p^nx=p^my$ with $m,n\in\mathbb{Z}$ and $x,y$ units in $\mathbb{Z}_p$. Then $p^{n-m}=yx^{-1}$. The right hand side shows that $p^{n-m}$ is a unit, so $m=n$ and $1=yx^{-1}$. Thus $x=y$ as well.

Applying this to your question, observe that $p^{-n}=p^{-n}\cdot 1$ is already of this form and that the $p$-adic expansion of $1$ is $1+0\cdot p+0\cdot p^2+\ldots$

---

If you would like to have a better grasp of this topic, I highly recommend getting a copy of [$p$-adic Numbers: An Introduction](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/3540629114). There is also a good amount of content on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-adic_number).

### An analogy

In $\mathbb{C}$, every non-zero element can be represented in polar form $z=re^{i\theta}$. Where $\vert z\vert=r$ and $e^{i\theta}$ is an element of the unit circle. The "unit circle" in $\mathbb{Q}_p$ is in some sense the units of $\mathbb{Z}_p$. So writing $q=p^{\nu_p(q)}u$ (where $u$ is a unit of $\mathbb{Z}_p$) is analogous to having a polar form for $p$-adic numbers.

Comment: J. David Taylor Could you explain me what you do from "For existence..", till the end? :/

Comment: Why does $z=q \cdot |q|_p$ have norm $1$?

Comment: J.David Taylor I understand... Could you also explain me why $z$ is of the form $q \cdot |q|_p$ ?

Comment: It's the definition of that variable in the proof. I changed the post to clarify.

Comment: J.David Taylor So each time, we write an element of $\mathbb{Q}_p$ as $p^nz$, is $z$ of the form $q \cdot |q|_p$ ?

Comment: No, what is important is that $z$ is a unit. It doesn't have to represented as $q\vert q\vert_p$, but it is true that every unit can be represented like that. The form $p^nz$ is unique for non-zero $p$-adic numbers (i.e. there is one and only one way to write each number that way). The form $q\vert q\vert_p$ is not unique at all (there are infinitely many ways to write a unit in that way).

Comment: A ok!!! Is the p-adic expansion of $\frac{1}{p^n}$ equal to $1 \cdot p^{-n}+ 0 \cdot p^{-n+1}+ \dots+ 0 \cdot p^{0}+ 0 \cdot p+0 \cdot p^2+ \dots$ ?

Comment: Yes. Usually we omit the zero terms because they are unnecessary, and just write $\frac{1}{p^n}$.

Comment: As another analogy, the decimal expansion of $\frac{1}{10^3}$ is $0.00100000000\ldots$. Usually, we drop the sequence of never ending zeros and write $0.001$.